# How to change the PDF reader of Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, pdf-reader, chromium, xdg

It seems Chromium uses `xdg-open` to open PDF files.

How do I change it to another PDF reader?

I'm using Linux Mint 8 LXDE.

Comment: Please, just add comments. Only answer your question if you know the answer for sure and it IS an answer. This way its a comment amongst the answers.

Comment: Second note: PLEASE do NOT write new answers. Just comment HERE.. HERE. That's all.

Answer (score 6):

This command edits the configuration file to use `xpdf` as the default PDF viewer:

`xdg-mime default xpdf.desktop application/pdf`

More details about `xdg-open` can be found here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open

Answer (score 1):

Check these:
`/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
`~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`

And the command `xdg-mime`. Use `man xdg-mime` to RTFM :))).

Comment: is it a bug of chrome?

does xdg-mime use .local/ list file?

Comment: Try the other system wide configuration file. OR you can install Adobe reader.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem the OP describes on Ubuntu 10.04. It seems I had entries for both xpdf AND evince in /etc/mailcap.

```
application/pdf; /usr/bin/xpdf '%s'; test=test "$DISPLAY" != ""; description=Portable Document Format; nametemplate=%s.pdf
application/x-pdf; /usr/bin/xpdf '%s'; test=test "$DISPLAY" != ""; description=Portable Document Format; nametemplate=%s.pdf
application/x-dia-diagram; dia '%s'; description="DIA diagram"; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.dia
audio/basic; /usr/bin/esdplay '%s'
audio/x-wav; /usr/bin/esdplay '%s'
audio/x-aiff; /usr/bin/esdplay '%s'
application/pdf; evince '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.pdf
application/x-pdf; evince '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; nametemplate=%s.pdf
```

removing/commenting out the entries for xpdf resolved the issue for me